# Write Custom Struct type to malloc Void

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, malloc

I am trying to write "any" kind of struct to a void array (Basically I'm trying to define an arraylist in C for any kind of datatype. I know that implementations already exist but I'm trying to learn because I'm kind of a beginner in C). I know how big the "data to add" is and I have the location in memory and know where the data should be placed. This is the current function that I came up with it but it doesn't work:

```
void addData(List *c, void* Item) {
    c->data = realloc(c->data, c->amountOfItems+1);
    ((char*)c->data)[c->dataTypeInBytes * c->amountOfItems - c->dataTypeInBytes] = Item;
    c->amountOfItems++;
}
```

c-> Data is a void malloc pointer. void* Item is the item to be added.
Basically, I try to put the Item value at the last (char*) location in c->data.
What exactly am I doing wrong? Also, what would be the best approach to get the data again from the allocated memory? My approach would be to convert `c->data` to a `char*` array and go to `c->data[c->dataTypeInBytes * c->amountOfItems - c->dataTypeInBytes]` and get `c->dataTypeInBytes` bytes. put each of those bytes in a char array with `c->dataTypeInBytes` length and return a void pointer to that, which then gets casted to the correct datatype outside the function. Would there be a better way to do that or straight up "define" a datatype with a specific size in Bits?

Comment: What is the meaning of `dataTypeInBytes`? You are storing pointers.

Comment: You `realloc` memory to hold `c->amountOfItems+1` **bytes**, yet you try to store something at offset `c->dataTypeInBytes * (c->amountOfItems - 1)`. unless `dataTypeInBytes` is less than 2, that will cause out of bounds access. If you want to store `c->amountOfItems+1` **pointers** you need to add `*sizeof(void*)` to your `realloc` size.

Comment: For me it is not really clear what you want to store. Generic lists normally just store pointers. They don't need to mess around with the size of the items. You seem to confuse storing pointers and storing the data. You might edit your question to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates how you plan to use that function. What items do you want to feed in, etc.